# How can I connect to MS SQL and Oracle databases from Perl when the credentials are stored in a separate file?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, perl, dbi

I am on a RedHat machine with the Unix ODBC drivers installed. I have used a construct like the following to connect to MySQL databases for a long time:

```
my @connection_userTracking = (
    "DBI:mysql:;" 
        . "mysql_read_default_file=/var/www/.my.cnf;" 
        . "mysql_read_default_group=myProject",
    undef,
    undef,
    {   PrintError => 0,
        RaiseError => 1,
        AutoCommit => 1
    }
);
```

This lets me store my database credentials in a separate file instead of hard-coding them in my Perl script. I assume that there must be something similar for MS SQL and Oracle. What is the format of the connection string for each?

I tried:

```
my @connection_MSSQL = (
    "DBI:ODBC:;" 
        . "mysql_read_default_file=/var/www/.my.cnf;" 
        . "mysql_read_default_group=myProjectMSSQL",
    undef,
    undef,
    {   PrintError => 0,
        RaiseError => 1,
        AutoCommit => 1
    }
);
```

with the DSN, username, and password in the config file but it barfs with the message:

> failed: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified

I added the DSN back to the code making the first line

```
"DBI:ODBC:DSN=my.db.host.com;"
```

and that barfs as well with the error

> failed: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''

I am not an expert with Linux ODBC so perhaps it is possible to put usernames and passwords in the system odbc.ini file but I don't like that. I would rather have project-specific files.

Is this sort of thing possible for MS SQL and Oracle?

Comment: This might be obvious, but all of the `mysql_` connection options are specific to, well, MySQL. Each database driver has its own set of options that aren't shared with other drivers. The options for ODBC are documented [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::ODBC).

Comment: heh, not obvious to me in this case. <facepalm>

Comment: A general cross-database solution would be to write a chunk of code that reads the information from these configuration files and uses them to establish the connection.  Oracle would allow you to have operating system authentication or to use a wallet which has the credentials stored securely.